# "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL" in debian 8.2

Tags: python, ssl, pip, debian-jessie

I'm connecting to a virtual server that I rented through `ssh`.

Its os is Debian 8.2.

I installed `python 3.7` and pip.

When I want to install any package with pip I get this error:

```
pip install django
```

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
> however the ssl module in Python is not available. WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL
> because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/ WARNING:
> Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
> status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to
> HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/
> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None,
> redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
> available.")': /simple/django/ WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1,
> connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
> broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module
> is not available.")': /simple/django/ WARNING: Retrying
> (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
> after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL
> because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/django/ Could not
> fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/django/: There was a problem
> confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/django/ (Caused by
> SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not
> available.")) - skipping ERROR: Could not find a version that
> satisfies the requirement django (from versions: none) ERROR: No
> matching distribution found for django WARNING: pip is configured with
> locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is
> not available. Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There
> was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL
> because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

I installed `libssl-dev` already, and trying `pip install ssl` won't help and I get the same error.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When you got this type of error you just need to re-setup or re-config your python setup using given commands:

1. `sudo apt install build-essential`
2. `sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget`
3. `mkdir ~/python-source-files`
4. `wget -P ~/python-source-files https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/Python-3.7.5.tgz`
5. `tar xvzf Python-3.7.5.tgz`
6. `cd Python-3.7.5`
7. `./configure --with-openssl`
   or
   `./configure --enable-optimizations`
8. `sudo make altinstall`

I have fixed same issue using these commands.
If you have any query you can ask.

Answer (score 1):

you can always skip https (on your own risk) by explicitly declaring you trust the pypi.org

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org django
```

you can also put it on pip.ini file under [global]

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.org
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error! Do you think it may be due to bad installation of python? I'm using python3.7.9

Comment: try this:
--trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org